# How to make firestore list view loading more documents when scrolling up?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use a `FirestoreListView()` for a chat. In this chat, I want to load more Messages when I scroll up and not when I am scrolling down.

In my Firebase Firestore collection, I have documents as messages.

So my question is: How to Make `FirestoreListView()` load more documents when I scroll up?

Somebody can give me please an answer or an alternative solution to load more documents when scrolling up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is not for loading more messages when you scroll up. For me the solution was to make it with a button that loads more data from the firebase with the `.where()` method and the time stamp:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("chats")
  .doc(documentId)
  .collection("messages")
  .where("timestamp", isLessThan: timestamps[0])
  .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
  .limit(20)
  .get()
  .then((value) {...});
```

---

**Now the list view shows the oldest messages first.**

To solve that look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOV2V0asFaE

---

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you're talking about here has a particular term **Pagination** which is a highly scalable practice while making any feed. Try this, refresh the screen again once the user reaches the bottom

```
Widget _buildBody(FeedState state) {
switch (state.status) {
  case FeedStatus.loading:
    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  default:
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () async {
        context.read<FeedBloc>().add(FeedFetchPosts());
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: state.posts.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final post = state.posts[index];
          final likedPostsState = context.watch<LikedPostsCubit>().state;
          final isLiked = likedPostsState.likedPostIds.contains(post!.id);
          final recentlyLiked =
              likedPostsState.recentlyLikedPostIds.contains(post.id);
          return PostView(
            post: post,
            isLiked: isLiked,
            recentlyLiked: recentlyLiked,
            onLike: () {
              if (isLiked) {
                context.read<LikedPostsCubit>().unlikePost(post: post);
              } else {
                context.read<LikedPostsCubit>().likePost(post: post);
              }
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
}}
```

Comment: i want to load more documents when the user scrolls up and not when user scroll down